# What is the possibility for a gamma ray photon to pass through a composite particle like a proton?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, subatomic

As I know, the photon can be either absorbed or reflected from a particle, but as baryons or other hadrons are composite particles is there a defined possibility of passing through the volume inside the particle, and if it is small is that because of the relativistic speeds of quarks inside a hadron?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the level of gamma ray energies, it is more complicated.  Once there is enough energy in the photon for production of particles , scattering of photons on nuclei  becomes more complicated. See what a [proton looks like here.](https://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/largehadroncolliderfaq/whats-a-proton-anyway/)

See [this experiment](https://cds.cern.ch/record/540474/files/0202034.pdf) how many channels with created particles there are .

elastic γp → V  , V a vector meson

proton dissociative γp → V N

photon dissociative γp → Gp , G a hadronic state

double dissociative γp → GN

hard non-diffractive γp → X

soft non-diffractive γp → X

In quantum mechanics  there will always be a probability  of the gamma going through only diffracting

In general it is all a matter of probabilities to be calculated with quantum field theory models.This is [a review](http://www.tunl.duke.edu/nnpss/lectures/11/NNPSS11-2-nobuilds.pdf) that goes into some details for high energy photon-proton interactions.